# How to edit RTF files on MVC website?

Tags: html, rtf

In our legacy win-form system we have support to edit RTF text. We are moving to MVC based solution, but there seems to be no support for RTF on MVC/Web.

I am trying to find any tool/plugin that can help in manipulating RTF on a MVC website.

Any suggestion would be grateful.

Comment: I recall I looked into this a few years ago and there was nothing.  There are, however, libraries that can convert between HTML and RTF that you could use on the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RTF files most likely will have to be presented as HTML

Please check out [How to make your own RTF Converter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter) which should be useful in your own project.